# как записать результат итераций в консоль

Tags: c#

Имеем цикл в цикле, допустим каждый цикл имеет по две итерации (их может быть больше, но для примера пусть будет две)

```
//первый цикл
foreach(string one in oonnee)  //List<string> oonnee
{
    
    //второй цикл 
    foreach(string two in ttwwoo) //List<string> ttwwoo 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(one + two);
    }
}
```

вопрос заключается в том, как мне записать в консоль во-втором цикле только результат - ПЕРВОЙ ИТЕРАЦИИ первого цикла и второго цикла и результат ВТОРОЙ ИТЕРАЦИИ первого цикла и второго цикла

чтобы в консоль вывело: (будет отлично, если это можно будет реализовать во-втором цикле console.writeline)

text1 } результат первой итерации первого цикла

text2 } результат первой итерации второго цикла

text3 } результат второй итерации первого цикла

text4 } результат второй итерации второго цикла

Comment: вообще вам бы познакомиться с Linq, эти все итерации будут восприниматься гораздо легче без циклов `Console.WriteLine(oonnee.First())` но для списка можно по индексу `Console.WriteLine(oonnee[0])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разумеется, в данной ситуации логичнее смотрится замена цикла foreach на цикл for и в такой ситуации вам не придётся вводить лишних сущностей/переменных. Просто добавите if перед выводом, где и проверите нужное значение.

Если же ну вот очень хочется оставить именно foreach - вводите доп. переменные. Для определения первого вхождения вам достаточно будет булевой переменной:

```
bool isFirst = true;
foreach(var num in nums)
{
    if(isFirst)
    {
          Console.WriteLine("something");
          isFirst= false;
    }
}
```

Для определения второго (пятнадцатого, сто шестого) повтора -- создавайте int'овую переменную, проверку if и инкремент.

```
int i = 0;
foreach(var num in nums)
{
    if(i == 1)
    {
          Console.WriteLine("something");
    }
    i++;
}
```

Для вашего кейса (первый и второй повтор, два цикла) надо будет две int'овые переменные завести, по одной на цикл.